# Gmock call function two times

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I would like to mock function that return void:

```
class FileDownloaderMock : public FileDownloader
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(downloadFile,
                       void(data *data_ptr));

};
```

in test case i would like to call this function 2 times, firstly should rise an exception and in the second times should work correctly. So my test case looks like this but doesn't work.

```
TEST_F(BCtrlTargetBdDownloaderTests, DownloaderShouldCorrectlyDownloadTargetBdInFirstAttempt)
{
     EXPECT_CALL(m_fileDownloader, downloadFile( DataReqMatcher(l_expectedReq) ) ).Times(2)
        .WillOnce(Throw(UpgradeException("Download failed") )); 
    }
```

The console output:

> to few actions specified in EXPECT_CALL(m_fileDownloader, downloadFile(
>   DataReqMatcher(l_expectedReq) ))... Expected to be called twice, but
>   has only 1 WillOnce().

So how can I solve this puzzle? 
Best Regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `EXPECT_CALL` configuration should look like

```
 EXPECT_CALL(m_fileDownloader, downloadFile( DataReqMatcher(l_expectedReq) ) )
    .Times(2)
    .WillOnce(Throw(UpgradeException("Download failed")))
    .WillOnce(Return());
```